# sorting list in a list

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have two classes

```
public class X
{
    string title;
}

public class Y
{
    string name;
    IList<X> testList;
}
```

I have a list like below

```
IList<Y> myList = new List<Y>();
```

I want to sort myList based on the name and title

How can I do it?

Comment: Which "title" do you want to sort on? The first title? The number of titles? The first-if-ordered? You need to be more specific with your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
 var sorted = lstY.OrderBy(c => c.name).ToList().Select(d => { d.testList.OrderBy(f => f.title); return d; });
```

Comment: +1 and if you order by the two at the same tiem .OrderBy(d=>d.Title).ThenBy(d=>d.Name)

Comment: i want to first sort by name then by title

Comment: thanks but i cannot access name as you have indicated bcos it is in another list

Comment: Having created a sample with the OP's classes, I could not get your use of the ForEach to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.OrderBy(x => x.name).ThenBy(y => y.testList.Min(z=>z.title));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one option but not the only option. Add a public or internal getter to class Y:

```
public IEnumerable<X> TestList{get{return testList.OrderBy(x=>x.title);}}
```

When retrieving your list of Y, clearly you can sort it by name:

```
myList.OrderBy(y=>y.name);
```

And for whatever processing you are doing, such as diplaying the list of Y, you would display Y.name and foreach X in TestList the X.title will be sorted.

or even without that second getter:

```
myList.OrderBy(y=>y.name).Select(y=>new{y.name, testList=y.testList.OrderBy(t=>t.title)}).Dump();
```